# Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice

Tags: react-native, xcode13

I am building a ReactNative application.
Able to run the app from xcode to device or simulator.

But while exporting i am facing the following error

Logs doesn't show which library causing the issue.

Fyi., I am using M1 Pro Macbook

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research and findings. I got a solution to *delete all java .class or any zip class* from project before exporting. I think the App store checks the compatibility of your project before uploading if any unrecognized file is found then it gives an error of Mach-O slice

Delete step by step each type of file and try to export. you will come to know which type is not supporting for export.

I didn't find any documentation supporting it but this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your signing certificate and provisioning profile. You might have a different signing certificate locally compare to the certificate that you set up on apple developer site.